# How to get info from a child table using PDO in PHP with SQL?

Tags: php, sql

How do I get information (via a parent table), from a child table that's using a foreign key that references the parent.

For example:

Table: **user_list** (parent)

```
-----------------------------
first_name | Last Name | ID |
-----------------------------
   john    | Appleseed |  4 |
           |           |    |
```

Table: **user_info**: (child)

```
----------------------------------------------
     email         |  password | userlist_ID |
----------------------------------------------
jappleseed@me.com  |   ******* |       4     |
```

Let's say I have John Appleseed's info stored in an array:

```
$johnsInfo;
```

How can I then retrieve John's email from the user_info table?

I'm trying this atm:

```
db->query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE userlist_ID = :ID", $johnsInfo);
```

Not sure if that's the right way of doing things though.

Comment: You need to go and read the MySQL documentation about JOIN statements: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: i think this is enough `select b.email from user_list a,user_info b where a.id=b.userlist_id and a.first_name="john" and a.lasst_name="appleseed"`

Comment: Can someone explain what the left and right table actually means? Does left mean it's a parent and right mean it's a child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a real example, you should just make the two tables into one table.  Generally if tables have 1:1 correspondence, you should put them together (though, there are special cases when you shouldn't).

Anyway, you'd want to do something like:

```
SELECT ul.*, ui.* FROM user_list ul
LEFT JOIN user_info ui
  ON ui.userlist_ID=ul.ID
WHERE ul.ID = :ID
```

There are different kinds of joins.  Check out the MySQL documents (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) or search for something like "database joins" to find out which one will end up working for you.

Comment: It's just a simplified example for the purposes explaining what I'm trying to do. btw what do you mean by 1:1 correspondence?

Comment: 1:1 means "one to one".  It just means that for every entry in user_list, you have exactly one entry in user_info.  No more, no less.  Other examples are 1:n, n:n, and n:1 (one-to-many, many-to-many, and many-to-one).  Search for "database normalization" and you'll learn a ton more about it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the SQL you need

```sql
SELECT user_list.ID
      ,user_list.first_name
      ,user_list.last_name 
      ,user_info.email
      ,user_info.password           
FROM user_list 
INNER JOIN user_info
ON user_list.ID = user_info.userlist_ID 
WHERE user.ID = :ID
```